# Closed question of a problem with shown attempt...please help me!

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, homework-and-exercises

Sorry, I have done a question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/688541/291611) where I have presented a problem that I have solved. I know that usually the questions are closed without any suggestions or help by the user if a problem is proposed to do without any attempt of working. I have tried to do work but I am not sure of my steps and I have a specific doubt linked to the use of information of the problem...why anyone cannot help me?

Comment: *"I know that usually the questions are closed without any suggestions or help by the user if a problem is proposed to do without any attempt of working."* While showing your work is *good*, this alone does not suffice to make a question on-topic here (note that the closing notice does *not* say anything about showing your work). Is there something specific that gave you the impression showing your work alone would make the question acceptable here?

Comment: If you need assignment help you will have to go elsewhere…. Your instructor might be a good first step.

Comment: @ACuriousMind And yet this a common thing told to users on such questions, unfortunately. Comments along the lines of "You need to show your work before we will help you". I'm not sure what to do to combat this misunderstanding.

Comment: @BioPhysicist not sure it’s commonly told, although it is told *by some*, although it is clearly not enough…